# How do I include a query as a parameter in python requests post statement?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, postman

When I run a Post Statement with a query in the body on the Postman Application it looks like this and works great:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QABmY.png)

I am trying to do the same thing with Python using the request library. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests  
query ={
"dataset": "keywordgroup",
"dimension": ["time", "domain", "domain:id","keywordgroup"],
"dimensionOptions": {"time": "weekly"},
"filter": [["time", "eq", "202101"], ["keywordgroup:id", ["-1"]],
["search_engine", [["1", "34"]]]],
"measures": ["pos_band_2","blended_pos_band_2"],
"count":1000,
"offset":0
}  
headers = {"Content-Type": 'application/json'}  
response = requests.post("https://api.brightedge.com/3.0/query/123456",  auth('myemail@gmail.com','mypassword'), headers = headers, data= query)  
print(response.text)
```

output:

```
{"error": {"errorcode": 0, "errormsg": "Missing POST 'query' parameter"}}
```

I am not sure why it isn't picking up on the query parameter. Does the query not go in the data parameter of the Post Statement? Do I need to format the query variable differently?

Comment: Perhaps you should use `json` as parameter name instead of `data`?

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for response, I tried using json as a parameter but got the same output

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, just made the whole statement a string. Then just said 'data = body' instead of 'data = query':

```
body = "query={\"dataset\": \"keywordgroup\",\"dimension\": [\"time\", \"domain\", \"domain:id\",\"keywordgroup\"],\"dimensionOptions\": {\"time\": \"weekly\"},\"filter\": [[\"time\", \"eq\", \"202101\"], [\"keywordgroup:id\", [\"-1\"]],[\"search_engine\", [[\"1\", \"34\"]]]],\"measures\": [\"pos_band_2\",\"blended_pos_band_2\"],\"count\":1000,\"offset\":0}"
```

The parameter was looking for a string as opposed to a variable.